# How does one use igraph with PySpark?

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark, igraph, spark-graphx

Can the "regular" python package igraph-python be used with PySpark?  I have a use-case where I want the functionality of igraph, but our graph is too big to fit into memory on one machine, so we'd like to use dataframes and PySpark to distribute the computation.  Can this be done?

I am trying to avoid the Apache Spark graphX, as it does not have the functionality of igraph.

Comment: I don't think you can do this in general.

Comment: Did you try doing this? What was your conclusion?

Comment: I am also interested in this!